# Weblogic 12.x Upgrade Issue

Tags: java, web-services, soap, weblogic, weblogic12c

We recently upgraded our weblogic version from Weblogic 10.3.x to Weblogic 12.x. 
We were using the below piece of code which used to run successfully but now is giving exceptions as below.

Code which is giving the exception

```
SOAPFactory inst = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
```

Exception:

```
javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SOAP Factory: Provider weblogic.webservice.core.soap.SOAPFactoryImpl not found.
```

Not sure which jars are missing . Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which Weblogic Version exactly? I use 12.1.3.0.0 and can't reproduce it.